# Replace DIV content based on specified existing content on page load by grabbing className

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I want to replace the existing content of the DIV based on it's specific content.

For example:

```html
<div class="className">1</div>
<div class="className">2</div>
<div class="className">3</div>
```

1 will render a specific new content as well as 2 and 3.

It has to be on window.load
Grabbed by ClassName

The current content is generated internally therefor I want to replace it with the new content which will be rendered on the website.

I have tried this but it doesn't work and I can't find specific solution, I've been searching for hours.
https://codepen.io/alessandramilburn/pen/rNOwpXW?editors=1010

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` return an array of elements that match the specified selector. Use `document.getElementsByClassName("x")[0].innerHTML` to get innerHTML of the first element that match the selector.

Comment: thank you, I tried that but it still the same https://codepen.io/alessandramilburn/pen/rNOwpXW?editors=1010

Comment: In both the places.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! It works now.

Comment: Any clue why it's only replacing the first div but not the second? Here's the updated code https://codepen.io/alessandramilburn/pen/rNOwpXW?editors=1010

Comment: Like I said, `getElementsByClassName` return an array of elements that match the specified selector. In your case, you need to iterate this array, check the content and then make the change.